# Loading a post type in a page under a tab

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs, custom-post-type

I have a page with three tabs.
I am using nav-tab-wrapper class and php to to check which tab is active.
My third tab is a custom post types for logging.
I am trying to load the custom post type under the tab and not redirect to another page. I have not figured out how to do this yet.

I tried using a href="page" but it redirects to the post types page.
I tried to use href= page&tab, then include the page on that tab. This causes an error.

```
<?php $active_tab = isset($_GET['tab']) ? $_GET['tab'] :   'entries'; // end if ?>

    <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
        <a href="?page=test-app&tab=entries" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'entries' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Entries</a>
        <a href="?page=test-app&tab=maps" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'maps' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Maps</a>
        <a href="?page=test-app&tab=logs" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'logs' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Logs</a>
    </h2>

    <form method="post" action="options.php">

        <?php
if ($active_tab == 'entries') {
    include 'entries.php';
} else if ($active_tab == 'maps') {
    include 'maps.php';
} else if ($active_tab == 'logs'){
// THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO LOAD THE POST TYPE TABLE. I WANT TO LOAD THE PAGE UNDER THE TAB.
}
```

Expected: logs (post_type) table loads under logs tab

Actual Results: I can redirect to the page but I do not know how to load under the actual tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you have to do is doing a custom query for that post type to fetch the posts of that type inside that condition ( $active_tab == 'logs' ). You can do it by WP_Query . To know more about WP_Query, please check this link: https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/

Here you will find the info regarding how to use this function with all the possible parameters.

Here in your code, this would be something like the code below.

```
else if ($active_tab == 'logs'){

// THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO LOAD THE POST TYPE TABLE. I WANT TO LOAD THE PAGE UNDER THE TAB.

 $arg = array(
   'post_type' => {POST TYPE NAME},
  );

  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  // The Loop
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        // Do Stuff, here you print anything regarding your post, i have printed the title for the current post as an example
         the_title()
      } // end while
  } // endif

  // Reset Post Data
   wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate it a lot!